# Analytical Question for GRE

Tags: analysis, contest-math

In a book prep. MCQ's in analytical portion a question says:

> "The chairs in the school hall can be set out in 35 equal rows or in 45 equal rows or in 105 equal rows are:"

I'm unable to sort out its meaning to state.

Comment: You have to find an integer that is the lcm of those $3$ numbers.

Comment: I did that but the question meaning is ambigious

Comment: insert "that" between "hall" and "can"??

Comment: @VarunIyer I think his problem is that the answer is not uniquely determined. And the third number doesn't give you a new condition.

Comment: -1 for ...........?

Comment: I don't understand -1 in such  a situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question says, If there are $x$ chairs in school hall, You can arrange them in $35$ (complete) Rows, $45$ Rows or $105$ Rows

That means
 $$x \equiv 0 \mod(35)$$
$$x \equiv 0 \mod(45)$$
$$x \equiv 0 \mod(105)$$

So,
$$x \equiv 0 \mod(315)$$

Basically, $x$ is LCM of $35,45,105$ or positive multiple of LCM

i.e. $x$ can be  $315,630,945, \cdots ,345(k)$

($k \in \mathbb N$)

Comment: @JavedIqbal I hope this helps

Comment: I accepted @Digital